# How to check submodules in Python with hasattr

Tags: python, import, module, hasattr

At runtime, the Python code gets the name of a submodule to load, which I don't know before. Now, I want to check, if this submodule exists inside an existing module. Consider this structure, where `foo` and `bar` can be specified:

```
master/
|
|- __init__.py
|
|- foo/
|  |
|  |- __init__.py
|
|- bar/
   |
   |- __init__.py
```

Now, usually I do this, which works for defs and variables:

```
import master

unknown_submodule = "foo"
if hasattr(master, unknown_submodule):
    pass # all's well
```

or I'm catching the AttributeError, which works equally.

However, with the above file structure, I'm not able to bring this approach up and working. `hasattr()` returns always False (that is, there is always an AttributeError thrown).

If I look at `dir(master)`, I see this output:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

and even explicitly specifying `__all__` in `master/__init__.py` doesn't help, but changes the dir() to

```
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a way to achieve these kinds of tests? (Btw: Python 2.6 on Win/Cygwin, if that's of any interest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules are not attributes of their parent modules unless stated explicitly. Simply try to import the module and catch `ImportError`:

```
try:
    __import__("os.peth", fromlist=[os])
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'stated explicitly'? I thought, that's what `__all__` was for? Do you happen to have a pointer at hand for a useful explanation? (Other than http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html or http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm )
Apart from that, yes the `__import__()` does what is requested.

Comment: No, `__all__` determines what gets imported when you say `from ... import *`. But this is not related to your problem. If you have a module `A` and a module `A.B`, then importing `A` does not magically add a member `B` to `A`—only if `A` itself imports `A.B`. To access `A.B` you have to import `A.B`, not `A`. In the case of `os.path` importing `os` works because `os` does actively import `os.path`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I start to get a grip on that matter.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to check submodule existence and since I'm using python 3.4.1, I'm giving a new answer to the question:

In python 3.4.1 you can use `importlib.util.find_spec(name, package=None)` (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec)

```
import importlib
module_exists = importlib.util.find_spec('path.to.my.module')
```

That easy =)

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
try:
 import module.submodule

except ImportError:
  print 'failed or whatever'
```

Comment: If `master/__init__.py` does not actively import `master.foo`, then `master` just has no member called `foo`. If you just import `master`, then `master.foo` raises an `AttributeError` regardless of whether `master.foo` exists.